# How to add a Navigator Push to a Flutter button widget? The element type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Quite new to Flutter states and still more to learn. How can I include a Navigation.push to a Widget button made? The error that shows in the terminal is: "The element type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'."

I am trying to add function to filter buttons: Below are the parameters of the filter:
a. Total of 3 filter buttons mimicking toggle button behavior.
b. The default state is nothing is selected for the buttons which lists all the archive journals (no filter applied).
c. Would be ideal if the buttons will be identical in size.

Below is the code I have currently. Only the Navigation.push part is flagged as error. Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
class Filter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterState createState() => _FilterState();
}

class _FilterState extends State<Filter> {
  int selected;
  Map<String, Function> funct;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 5),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 10),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
          ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 3),
                child: Text(
                  'Type Search',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Georgia",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Color(0xFFA86A6A),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 300,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .94,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TypeFilter(
                      onPressed: onPressed,
                      selected: selected,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onPressed(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selected = selected == index ? null : index;
    });
  }
}

class TypeFilter extends StatelessWidget {
  CategoriesTypeFilter({
    Key key,
    this.onPressed,
    this.selected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final void Function(int selectedIndex) onPressed;
  final int selected;
  Map<String, Function> funct;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        TypeFilterButton('Igneous', 0),
        (funct['type']('Igneous')),
        TypeFilterButton('Metamorphic', 1),
    (onPressed () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>MetamorphicAnimatePage());
        },
        ),
        TypeFilterButton('Sedimentary', 2),
        (funct['type']('Sedimentary')),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget TypeFilterButton(String textData, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onPressed(index),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 5, 0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 10, 2, 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: selected == index ? Color(0xFFA86A6A) : Color(0xFF5A2020),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
        ),
        child: Text(
          (textData),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          maxLines: 2,
          style: TextStyle(
              height: 1.2,
              fontFamily: 'Georgia',
              fontSize: 15,
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How you are handling `_FilterState` variable? can you simplify the code producing the same error?

Comment: hi @Yeasin, filter buttons are mimicking toggle button behavior, so only one button (filter) can be selected and change color upon pressing. The default state is nothing is selected for the buttons which lists all the archive journals (no filter applied).

Comment: are you using null-safety?

Comment: hello @Yeasin, I am using an older version of Flutter, so pre-null safety required. ^_^"

Comment: Oh, can you include on top of the question. And on `TypeFilter` using `CategoriesTypeFilter` constructor

Comment: hi @YeasinSheikh, I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply change `final void Function(int selectedIndex) onPressed;`

TO `final VoidCallback onPressed;`

Comment: hello @William, the change for the onPressed suggested didn't work. :( It resulted to this warning => The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'. And added errors for the onPressed and index.

Comment: In this case i recommend you to remove the argument `final void Function(int selectedIndex) onPressed;` from here (`int selectedIndex`) and receive it on your class `TypeFilter`

Comment: hi @William, from here (int selectedIndex) and receive it on your class TypeFilter? thanks.